# Best practice of using pkg-config in meson build system

Tags: meson-build

In Makefile, I can write something like below to get the dependencies libs.

```
LIBS:= $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKGS))
```

But in meson.build, I don't know how to write simply like this.

I can use `run_command` to get libs like below,

```
r = run_command('pkg-config', '--cflags', 'gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0')
if r.returncode() != 0
  # it failed
  errortxt = r.stderr().strip()
  message(errortxt)
endif
output = r.stdout().strip().split(' ')
message(output)
foreach inc : output
    add_global_arguments(inc, language : 'c')
endforeach
```

so what is best practice to use pkg-config ?

**---- UPDATE ----**

Using

```
dependency('gstreamer-video-1.0', 'pkg-config')
```

will take all effects on `build.ninja`

```
 LINK_ARGS = -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--start-group -lm -Wl,-rpath,/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.1/lib:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64 -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.1/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64 /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.1/lib/libnvdsgst_meta.so /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.1/lib/libnvds_meta.so /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.1/lib/libnvdsgst_helper.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstrtspserver-1.0.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so -Wl,--end-group
```

but not on `compile_commands.json`

```
[
  {
    "directory": "/home/ubuntu/work/deepstream-5.1/sources/apps/sample_apps/test3_meson/build",
    "command": "cc -Itest1.p -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/cuda-10.2/include -I../../../../includes -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/orc-0.4 -fdiagnostics-color=always -pipe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -g -DPLATFORM_TEGRA -pthread -MD -MQ test1.p/deepstream_test3_app.c.o -MF test1.p/deepstream_test3_app.c.o.d -o test1.p/deepstream_test3_app.c.o -c ../deepstream_test3_app.c",
    "file": "../deepstream_test3_app.c"
  }
]
```

So if changes meson.build, should better see effects in `build.ninja`.

Comment: I believe that's just the commands to compile that .c intro a .o file, there should be another entry in compile_commands.json to link the various .o files where the link arguments show up

Comment: But in my compile_commands.json, there is only one entry.

Comment: I see the includes for your dependencies in there, so the dependencies are registering

Answer (score 3):

Meson provides the `dependency()` abstraction for working with pkg-config, cmake, various *-config tools, and a few built in dependencies that Meson has to save everyone reimplementing them, you would simply write:

```
dep_gstreamer = dependency('gstreamer-1.0')
dep_gsreamer_video = dependency('gstreamer-video-1.0')
# note that each dependency call finds 1 dependency
```

then you'd pass them to your targets:

```
build_target(
  'name',
  sources,
  dependencies : [dep_gstreamer, dep_gstreamer_video]
)
```

Under the hood Meson will call pkg-config, parse the outputs, and create dependency objects that hold the various arguments to be passed. It can also fall back to using cmake or other even building those projects from source if necessary.

If you only want to pass the compiler flags, and not the linker flags as well, then you can do this:

```
dep_gstreamer = dependency('gstreamer-1.0').partial_dependency(compile_args : true)
```

You then pass that as a dependency like normal, as it is a dependency, but one that only passes compiler flags, and not link flags.

As an aside, you really shouldn't use `add_global_arguments()`, it affects all subprojects as well, instead use `add_project_arguments()`.

Comment: THX. I just get it.  By the way, I love meson at first sight. :)